# alamofire object mapper .. why print my project name?

Tags: swift, alamofire, mapper, objectmapper

[Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFpmf.png)

*Note*: This is my first swift file

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let encodingURL = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

    Alamofire.request(encodingURL!).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<channel>) in

        let MovieResponse = response.result.value

        print("결과: \(MovieResponse?.channel?.result as AnyObject)")
        print("타이틀: \(MovieResponse?.channel?.title as AnyObject)")
        print("토탈카운트: \(MovieResponse?.channel?.totalCount as AnyObject)")
        print("전체:\(MovieResponse?.channel as AnyObject)")
        print("아이템: \(MovieResponse?.channel?.item as AnyObject)")
        print("배우:\(MovieResponse?.channel?.item.first?.actor as AnyObject)")

    }
}
```

*Note*: second swift file

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

class channel : Mappable {
    var channel : channelComponents?
    required init?(map: Map){ }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        self.channel <- map["channel"]    
    }
}

class channelComponents : Mappable {
    var totalCount : Int?
    var result : Int?
    var title : String?
    var item : [item]

    required init?(map: Map){
       item = []       
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {          
        self.totalCount <- map["totalCount"]
        self.result <- map["result"]
        self.title <- map["q"]
        self.item <- map["item"]  
    }
}

class item : Mappable { 
    var actor : [Actor]

    required init?(map: Map) {       
        actor = []        
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {        
        self.actor <- map["actor"]     
    }
}

class Actor : Mappable {
    var content : String?
    var link : String?

    required init?(map: Map) { }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        self.content <- map["content"]
        self.link <- (map["link"])       
    }
}
```

**input**

```
 print("아이템: \(MovieResponse?.channel?.item as AnyObject)")
 print("배우:\(MovieResponse?.channel?.item.first?.actor as AnyObject)")
```

**output**

```
아이템: (
    "Movie_D.item"
)
배우:(
"Movie_D.Actor",
"Movie_D.Actor",
"Movie_D.Actor",
"Movie_D.Actor",
"Movie_D.Actor",
"Movie_D.Actor",
"Movie_D.Actor"
)
```

Movie_D is my project name.

I want to know the actor's name, but there is just my project name. (the count is right)

Comment: can you post your response raw value? also - try to translate comments from hangul, because in one place you refer to "actor" but in code it's written in korean.

Comment: Fixed up spacing and some semantics to make the question more understandable in English. Attempted to stick to author's tone/language as closely as possible, while condensing and clarifying a couple things that I understood (maybe incorrectly, but I hope not).

Comment: In addition to my edit, in terms of attacking the answer: if you added your data format @이재진 that would help answer the question -- as is, it seems that there is an `Actor` object from which you want to get the `actor's name`, but from information shown I'm not sure how that's stored in your app.

Comment: haha i'm so sorry about language ..it makes you guys more complex ;; anyway, now I can get data that I want ,but still I am curious about that problem...-_-

Answer (score 0):

You should cast the actor property to a `String` (assuming it is one) to properly display the actor's name in your `print` statement.

```
print("배우:\(String(describing: MovieResponse?.channel?.item.first?.actor))")
```